# How do I clone my cascading context menu for 'dllfile'?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, context-menu

I recently made a custom cascading context menu folder for applications on my computer. Everything works as I intended and I'd like to add this for dynamic link library files as well but I've hit a wall doing so. Here is the registry settings I used for the `exefile` key:

[image]

Adding my custom commands from the command store appear in the order I've specified and they all work correctly:

[image]

I have replicated what I want included in the `dllfile` key but I don't get `Binary Toolbox` in the context menu:

[image]

What's missing? It's my understanding that my custom commands need to be in the
command store, and declared in the `shell` key for the file type I choose as shown above. Does the dynamic link library class/key use a different registry key for command references?

Comment: Interesting, when I create a `Binary Toolbox` key there with your `icon` value and a blank `SubCommands` value, I get a (useless) Binary Toolbox item as the first entry in DLLs' context menus. Could you try blanking `SubCommands` and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes @BenN, I'll give it a try later today.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I discovered that I had the answer but I had some typos in my exported registry file. After re-exporting my modified `exefile`registry file I simply had to replace all occurrences of `exefile` with `dllfile` followed by importing the modified registry file.